# How to change format between currency and percent in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, format, google-visualization

I have made a chart in Google Charts. I have a range filter where I can filter out different years and so on, and I also have a select filter which I can choose which data I want to compare. But now to my question: How can I have a select filter which chooses between currency and percent? As you can see, I have a columnFilter (select) on the top. I want a "formatFilter" that changes the vAxis from percent and currency. Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WaUu2/320/)

[image]

Here's my code:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
          ['2012 Januari', 100, 126, 122, 232, 215],
          ['2012 Februari', 152, 254, 242, 168, 136],
          ['2012 Mars', 300, 232, 234, 195, 343],
          ['2012 April', 450, 242, 325, 121, 126],
          ['2012 Maj', 600, 224, 234, 151, 124],
          ['2012 Juni', 750, 121, 867, 152, 235],
          ['2012 Juli', 900, 942, 566, 267, 457],
          ['2012 Augusti', 950, 762, 363, 794, 279],
          ['2012 September', 105, 378, 345, 175, 345],
          ['2012 Oktober', 200, 284, 600, 228, 315],
          ['2012 November', 210, 453, 534, 378, 153],
          ['2012 December', 205, 166, 536, 274, 315],
          ['2013 Januari', 463, 134, 345, 267, 378],
          ['2013 Februari', 150, 234, 534, 271, 745]
        ]);

        var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
        columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
        var initState = { selectedValues: [] };
        // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
        for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() ; i++) {
            columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
            // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
            initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
        }
        // you can set individual columns to be the default columns (instead of populating via the loop above) like this:
         //initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(2));
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('lineDashboard_div'));

        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            containerId: 'lineChart_div',
            dataTable: data,
            options: lineChartOptions
        });

        var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'lineColumnFilter_div',
            dataTable: columnsTable,
            options: {
                filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
                ui: {
                    caption: "Compare",
                    label: false,
                    allowTyping: false,
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    allowNone: false,
                    selectedValuesLayout: 'below'
                }
            },
            state: initState
        });

        var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'lineRangeFilter_div',
            options: {
                filterColumnIndex: '1',
                ui: {
                    showRangeValues: false,
                    label: false
                }
            }
        });

        function setChartView() {
            var state = columnFilter.getState();
            var row;
            var view = {
                columns: [0]
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
                row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{ column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i] }])[0];
                view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
            }
            // sort the indices into their original order
            view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a - b);
            });
            chart.setView(view);
            chart.draw();
        }
        google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);
        dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chart);
        dashboard.draw(data);
        setChartView();
        columnFilter.draw();

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean with currency? Because that depends on locale. You could just have a checkbox or button that onclick depending on the current shown values, redraws the chart with the proper formatter

Comment: @juvian, I mean, in the Axis, the numbers in the array (A, B, C and so on). They have their number and %-mark in the axis. How can I toggle between % and $ or in my case: SEK?

Comment: Your image seems pretty different from the data on your code, but you need to use a number formatter: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter and you can put suffix option for a % or a $